# Validação HTML5 antes de prevenir envio formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou capturando o evento de `clique` em um botão de um formulário e estou usando  o `preventDefault()` para não enviar o formulário, porém ao fazer isso a validação do `HTML 5 (required, email, maxlength)` não funciona, como posso resolver isso?

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form-reseta-senha">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="inputbox" autocomplete="on" id="email" required />
    <label>CPF/CNPJ</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpfcnpj" class="inputbox mascara-cpfcnpj" id="cpfcnpj" autocomplete="on" required maxlength="18" min="14" />
    <label>Nova senha</label>
    <input type="password" name="senha" class="inputbox" id="senha" autocomplete="off" required />
    <label>Confirme a nova senha</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirmacaoSenha" id="confirmacaoSenha" class="inputbox" autocomplete="off" required />
    <button class="btn btn-full btn-primary" id="troca-senha">
        <div class="btn-texto">Trocar senha</div>
        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin white md-24" id="icon-btn" style="display:none"></i>
    </button>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>


$("#troca-senha").on("click", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log("cliquei!");});
```

Comment: lembrou do return???

Comment: Poste o código para podermos ajudar

Comment: Essas validações HTML5 só funcionam no submit.

Comment: coloquei o código ali, eu não tenho grandes conhecimentos em javascript, eu já faço a validação no backend queria só 'obrigar' o usuário a preencher os campos corretamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está tratando o evento `click`, que ocorre antes da submissão de fato, e antes da validação:

```
$("#troca-senha").on("click", function (event) { 
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log("cliquei!");
});
```

O evento que você precisa capturar é o `submit` do form, assim a validação irá rodar primeiro:

```
$("form").on("submit", function (event) { 
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log("cliquei!");
});
```

Se precisar, adicione um id ao form, para referenciá-lo.

Comment: é no submit mesmo, eu quero só validar o básico com o html e enviar a requisição via ajax. Eu já conhecia o evento submit mas não me liguei que o click vem antes... valeu !

Answer (score 0):

Se você está utilizando apenas a validação do HTML5, não há a necessidade alguma de javascript inclusive o `preventDefault()`, apenas um formulário, com um input `required` e um botão de submit

**Exemplo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="nome" required>
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Agora, se você pretende fazer a sua própria validação via javascript, deveria utilizar o evento `onsubmit` e um método que retorne se o formulário deve ser enviado e não no evento de `click` do botão...

```js
function validar(){
  if(document.getElementById("nome").value == "teste")
    return false;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar()">
    <p>não pode ser igual a "teste"</p>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: não vou validar com js, era só trocar o evento de click por submit, valeu

Answer (score 0):

O `button` sem um atributo `type`, dentro de um `form`, tem a função de `submit`. Ao cancelar o evento `click` do botão você está ao mesmo tempo cancelando o submit. Com isso as validações HTML5 serão ignoradas porque elas dependem do submit. Ou seja, ao colocar `event.preventDefault();` você está cancelando os efeitos do clique no botão, que seria o de submeter o formulário. Logo, sem submeter o formulário, as validações não surtem efeito.

Se você quer evitar que o formulário seja enviado mas fazer as validações normalmente capturando o clique no botão, pode usar o método `.one()` do jQuery. Ele irá criar um *event handler* do submit que será executado apenas 1 vez cada vez que você validar todos os campos do formulário, e então você poderá cancelar o submit nesse evento. Mas antes você precisa verificar se todos os campos com o atributo `required` foram preenchidos.

A propriedade `elemento.validity.valid` retorna *true* ou *false* de acordo com o `required` do elemento (pode ser usado com outros tipos de validações, como o `pattern`, por exemplo). Basta percorrer os elementos que contém o atributo `required`, e se algum não for válido, altera a variável para `false` evitando o método `.one()`. Se todos os campos forem válidos, o método `.one()` com o evento submit será ativado e o `preventDefault()` irá impedir o envio.

```js
$("#troca-senha").on("click", function (event) {

   console.log("cliquei!");
   
   var valido = true;

   $("form [required]").each(function(index, element){
      if(!element.validity.valid){
         valido = false;
         return;
      }
   });
   
   if(valido){
      
      // aqui chama o submit, mas é cancelado pelo preventDefault()
      $("form").one("submit", function(event){
         console.log("Evento submit cancelado");
         event.preventDefault();
      });

   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" class="form-reseta-senha">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="inputbox" autocomplete="on" id="email" required />
    <label>CPF/CNPJ</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpfcnpj" class="inputbox mascara-cpfcnpj" id="cpfcnpj" autocomplete="on" required maxlength="18" min="14" />
    <label>Nova senha</label>
    <input type="password" name="senha" class="inputbox" id="senha" autocomplete="off" required />
    <label>Confirme a nova senha</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirmacaoSenha" id="confirmacaoSenha" class="inputbox" autocomplete="off" required />
    <button class="btn btn-full btn-primary" id="troca-senha">
        <div class="btn-texto">Trocar senha</div>
        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin white md-24" id="icon-btn" style="display:none"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```